# Hard drive spins down & back up again every 10 seconds; no access shown in `fatrace`

Tags: linux, fedora, hard-disk

I'm running Fedora 23 on a low-power hard drive[*].  I can hear the hard drive clicking or spinning down & then back up, approximately **every 10 seconds**.  (And the activity LED flashing).

If I log in and run `sync; fatrace --timestamp`, I can't see any file access associated with the spin-up.

There's some periodic file accesses but they're all cached reads, e.g. to `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/fstab`.  In case `relatime` wasn't being applied for some reason, I tried mounting with `noatime`, but that didn't help.  I also disabled swap (`swapoff -a`).

The drive isn't designed for this & I expect it's eventually going to kill it.  It's not very energy-efficient either :).  Help!

[*] It's a NAS-type system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second thing I looked for was direct device access.  `sudo lsof /dev/sd*` showed nothing.  `cd /dev; fatrace --current-mount --timestamp` didn't show any associated accesses either.

At this point I needed to start stripping down to the kernel.  Lets try `systemctl isolate rescue.target`.  Strange, it bounces back to `default.target`.  Then `systemctl status` shows the system is degraded because `dmeventd` didn't want to stop while it's still monitoring devices (!)...  but the hard drive has stopped spinning back up (!!).

Indeed, on a non-degraded system, the problem goes away after `killall -9 dmeventd`.

How can it be so broken?  The reason is I started playing with `docker`, and since I use LVM it chose the devicemapper storage driver.[*]

```
dmeventd[5054]: dmeventd ready for processing.
lvm[5054]: Monitoring thin vg_fossil-docker--pool.
```

[*] It might also be a problem if you have LVM mirrors, raid, or snapshots... admittedly a possibility on a NAS system :(.  If you don't have any of these, e.g. just simple LVs or no LVM at all, then dmeventd doesn't have anything to monitor and it behaves itself.

---

Specifically dmeventd is doing these ioctls about every 10 seconds:

```
open("/dev/mapper/control", O_RDWR)     = 7
...
ioctl(7, DM_TABLE_STATUS
ioctl(7, DM_DEV_WAIT
```

I still think the spinup is a bug, but at least for my case there's an <del>obvious</del> workaround[*] and I'm not really worried I'm going to miss anything because of it.

[*] If you really want to stop dmeventd working, even though you have a thin pool which probably dies horribly if it runs out of space, search for `monitoring = 1` in `lvm.conf` and change the value to `0`.

---

Update: [The bug is fixed](https://www.redhat.com/archives/dm-devel/2016-January/msg00084.html) in the very next version of `lvm2`, `2.02.133`.