# Hearing the hard drive when nothing is supposed to use it

Tags: linux, monitoring, io, disk

Sometimes I hear the hard drive physically working when nothing is supposed to be using it. Is there a way for me to see what is activating it ?

Answer (score 2):

Install `iotop` package. This is version of `top` command that looks at how much IO each process is using.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern hard drives have their own controllers.  It could really be whatever:

- A cache (in the disk controller) written into the actual storage
- Speed regulation to ensure that the disk spins at the same speed all the time.
- The disk entered `standby` or `sleep` (some do it automatically, some don't, although that is configurable).
- Or an actual daemon reading/writing from/to it.

`hdparm` has several more-or-less standard ways to understand how a disk works, but many of the features are **not supported by many disks**.  A couple of useful queries to a disk are:

- `hdparm -b /dev/<disk>`: BUS state
- `hdparm -B /dev/<disk>`: Power management info (will it go into standby automatically?)
- `hdparm -M /dev/<disk>`: Acoustic management (speed control, although I never saw a single disk that supports this `hdparm` query)

These can be used to check whether the disk **may** do something on its own.  They cannot tell you whether the disk will actually do it, that's a decision made by the firmware inside.

The last option of my previous enumeration "an actual daemon reading/writing from/to the disk" may be checked with:

1. Use `hdparm -y /dev/<disk>` to force it into `standby` mode.
2. Wait a reasonable amount of time (an hour perhaps).
3. Use `hdparm -C /dev/<disk>` to check whether it remains in `standby` mode.

Disclaimer: Vast majority of disks do not support most `hdparm` (ATA/SATA) commands.  Yet, they often support at least some of them.  Your mileage may vary significantly.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu wrote `fatrace` for this purpose.

If you can't find it with `fatrace`, and there's no process opening the device node directly (`lsof /dev/sd*`), it's a kernel thing.

Example kernel bug: [Hard drive spins down & back up again every 10 seconds; no access shown in `fatrace`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253427/hard-drive-spins-down-back-up-again-every-10-seconds-no-access-shown-in-fatr)

One kernel thing to be aware of is periodic writeback.  Remember the filesystem uses a write-back cache.  [By default, un-synced writes can queued for 5 seconds before they are flushed to disk](https://serverfault.com/a/471303).

Answer (score 2):

You can get detailed info from the kernel (assuming it was configured with CONFIG_FTRACE) using [iosnoop](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/iosnoop), one of the scripts from the Brendan Gregg trace and performance collection. Eg:

```
$ sudo /opt/perf-tools-master/bin/iosnoop
Tracing block I/O. Ctrl-C to end.
COMM         PID    TYPE DEV      BLOCK        BYTES     LATms
chromium-bro 19962  R    8,0      21573632     16384      1.89
jbd2/sda3-41 416    WS   8,0      63562984     4096       2.00
kworker/1:1H 288    WS   8,0      129725080    32768      1.96
<idle>       0      WS   8,0      129725144    4096       0.39
jbd2/sda1-23 231    WS   8,0      8137984      4096       0.09
gawk         5839   WS   8,0      10314904     4096       0.35
jbd2/sda3-41 416    WS   8,0      173342200    4096       1.96
gawk         5839   WS   8,0      129725168    4096       0.33
emacs        9514   WS   8,0      132405432    65536      1.77
emacs        9514   WS   8,0      173343232    118784     1.77
...
```

Note also that disks have firmware that might provoke head activity, eg doing some sort of realignment check.